# jQuery implementation with Cargo Collective site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got [this site](http://cargocollective.com/amytdatta/Amyt-Datta) running on Cargo. At the bottom of this page i'm trying to create a simple 20 questions type game (the two columns of text). My objective is to create some kind of button which when clicked or hovered over changes the text-colour of the false statements.

Here's the jQuery i'm using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(".showtrue").click(function() { $('.false').css('color','#f5f5f5');return false;});$(".showfalse").click(function() { $('.false').css('color','#999999');return false; });</script>
```

showtrue is a function which will effectively hide the false statements by setting the text color to the bg color, showfalse resets showtrue.

Here is the HTML i'm using on the page:

```
<div class="column"><p>Digs disco<br><span class="false">Was born in the 70s</span><br>Grew up in a vicious part of town<br><span class="false">Reads mathematics textbooks to relax</span><br><span class="false">Begins the day with a hundred push-ups</span><br>Was attacked by cockroaches after shooting a lizard</div><div class="column"><p><span class="false">Is a vegetarian</span><br>Was born in the 60s<br>Didn't use a computer until 2012<br><span class="false">Is a completely self-taught musician</span><br>Often sleeps with his guitar next to him<br>Has played on a freezing stage lit by a single naked bulb</div>

Only some of the above is <a class="showtrue" href="#">true</a> / <a class="showfalse" href="#">Reset</a>
```

My code doesn't seem to do anything. However, my jQuery code seems to have messed with my Cargo CSS. For instance my top nav (which is supposed to be fixed) is now scrolling with the rest of the page. The "Running On Cargo" link which is supposed to be fixed with the top nav is now appearing above the top nav.

I'm not really sure how to address these issues and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your script in document.ready

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){  
    $(".showtrue").click(function() { 
          $('.false').css('color','#f5f5f5');
          return false;
    });
   $(".showfalse").click(function() { 
     $('.false').css('color','#999999');
     return false;
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: Wow very cool Yogesh! That works for the text-color change behaviour. However, my Cargo CSS still appears to be a bit wonky thanks to the JQuery. I know this is probably some deep hidden issue, perhaps with the way Cargo handles its own jQuery, but any thoughts?

Comment: "Running On Cargo" moved along with scrolling becoz `position:fixed`
CSS is applied to that element